# How can i manage multiple view in Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mergeadapter

**I want to show diffrent view in single Recycler view**
How can i do this.[image]

**In Kotlin**

Comment: Have you tried any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Your picture took from the [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/merge-adapters-sequentially-with-mergeadapter-294d2942127a) that describes how to merge 3 adapter into one recyclerView. So you can read it first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Recylerview view with Multiple View types.
Each View Type will have its own ViewHolder, all of them having the same adapter.

Have a look at the below article.
https://blog.mindorks.com/recyclerview-multiple-view-types-in-android